# MQClient in Docker

Tags: docker, ibm-mq, pymqi

I have a Windows grp and added a user to that grp to connect to MQ.
I'm using this user (userID in the below code) in my Python code to connect to a remote MQServer.

The Docker file uses Ubuntu image as base image. Can the Docker file with Ubuntu image and pymqi can connect to a remote MQServer using the Windows user in the Python code as below? I'm getting the below error, if I set user-1001 in the Dockerfile. The MQ Server is not part of the Docker image.

> pymqi.MQMIError: MQI Error. Comp: 2, Reason 2009: FAILED: MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN

If I don't use USER 1001 (dummy user) in the Dockerfile, I get AUTHORIZATION error.

Attached is the Dockerfile and below is the code.

Comment: I am assuming that you are using `pymqi` in your docker image, in which case you should also have the IBM MQ redistributable client. If so have you tried to run one of the samples that come with the redistributable client from your docker image, just to check the connectivity?

Comment: You say "Attached is the dockerfile and below is the code" but neither are present. Could you also update your question to show the authorization error that is seen please.